# jfrog Xray startup failure with router error " 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused"

Tags: jfrog-xray

Tried installing `xray`. After installation and start-up, the xray didn't work. I found the only erorr in logs. it shows

```
localhost:8046 (routers port) cant connect. besides there is not 8046 port listening on the server.

2023-08-23T08:41:02.629Z [jfxps] [INFO ] [02b179b60069f31b] [access_client_bootstrap:203   ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Cluster join: Retry 50: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
2023-08-23T08:41:03.219Z [jfxan] [INFO ] [630d230eae22abe2] [access_client_bootstrap:203   ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Cluster join: Retry 65: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
2023-08-23T08:41:04.510Z [jfxid] [INFO ] [d4cc8ac260df5182] [access_client_bootstrap:203   ] [main                ] (--wrapper--)Cluster join: Retry 65: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8046: connect: connection refused
[root@VM-0-8-centos etc]# netstat -tlnp |grep 8046
[root@VM-0-8-centos etc]#
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error you're encountering may be due to a lack of established communication between `Artifactory` and `Xray`. To resolve this, please follow these steps:

a) First, verify that port 8082 is accessible externally and that internal ports are not blocked. You can find more information on this by referring to the provided link.

b) Confirm that the Artifactory URL provided during installation is correct.

c) Alternatively, you can test port 8082 compatibility using the following commands:

```
curl -i http://ARTIFACTORY_IP:PORT/artifactory/api/system/ping
curl -i http://ARTIFACTORY_IP:PORT/router/api/v1/system/health
telnet Xray-IP 8082 # from the Artifactory machine
telnet Artifactory-IP 8082 # from the Xray machine
```